# Azure Function runs locally, but doesn't do anything after Docker container is built and run locally

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-functions, containers

I have an Azure Function, with custom imported python modules, that runs correctly when I use `func start` in the directory. But, the next step is to get it running locally in a `Docker` container. After I build and run ([following the Azure instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python)), nothing happens, and I get the following output:

```
info: Host.Triggers.Warmup[0]
      Initializing Warmup Extension.
info: Host.Startup[503]
      Initializing Host. OperationId: '9711d195-2ab7-4b93-8c53-dd577b6b70d5'.
info: Host.Startup[504]
      Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=9711d195-2ab7-4b93-8c53-dd577b6b70d5
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      LoggerFilterOptions
      {
        "MinLevel": "None",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": "None",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          }
        ]
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
      {
        "BatchSize": 1000,
        "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "IsEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      SingletonOptions
      {
        "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
        "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
        "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
        "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      HttpOptions
      {
        "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
        "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
        "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
        "RoutePrefix": "api"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
      Starting JobHost
info: Host.Startup[401]
      Starting Host (HostId=c8cdf3a0c1a6-2137340777, InstanceId=c64a8e95-4ded-4a90-ac41-461d9223ed24, Version=3.0.15417.0, ProcessId=1, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
info: Host.Startup[314]
      Loading functions metadata
info: Host.Startup[315]
      1 functions loaded
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Generating 1 job function(s)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Found the following functions:
      Host.Functions.BadFunc
      
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
      Initializing function HTTP routes
      No HTTP routes mapped
      
info: Host.Startup[412]
      Host initialized (107ms)
fail: Host.Startup[0]
      The listener for function 'Functions.BadFunc' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Functions.BadFunc' was unable to start.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_TimerStatusDirectory() in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusBlobReference(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 144
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String timerName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:line 99
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:line 72
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 69
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
info: Host.Startup[413]
      Host started (154ms)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher[0]
      Worker process started and initialized.
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Retrying to start listener for function 'Functions.BadFunc' (Attempt 1)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Listener successfully started for function 'Functions.BadFunc' after 1 retries.
info: Host.General[316]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F28FAECC'.
```

So it looks like the container is running after one failed start-up. Great. But why is nothing happening? I'm supposed to get Slack notifications if it runs correctly or fails. The `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.6-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.6

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

# install python dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# chrome install
#ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
   # ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

# install chromedriver used by Selenium
RUN LATEST=$(wget -q -O - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && ln -s $PWD/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

I use `docker build --tag <DOCKER_ID>/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0 .` to build the image, and I run it from Docker Desktop clicking "run."

I've closely followed [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-selenium-web-scraper-in-azure-functions-f156fd074503) on getting selenium working in a container. I have pointed my scraping function to the `chromedriver`, but I don't think that's the issue. Here is my `function.json` file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

And `local.settings.json` file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"
  }
}
```

File structure in VSCode:

```
FunctionDirectory
    |_ BadFunc
        | __init__.py
        | custom_mod1.py
        | custom_mod2.py
          ...
        | function.json
    |_ local.settings.json
       Dockerfile
       requirements.txt
       etc..
```

Am I missing something obvious on why I'm getting no results, when running the container locally?

Or would this have something to do with the actual `__init__.py` code, having a return type of `None` vs. something else?

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None: #should be something else?
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    
    # Class instantiation for the handling stuff ----
    name_handle_instance = dc.NameHandle()
    #calls other functions below...
```

Comment: do you have the values set for connection string?

Comment: @Sajeetharan - unless you are talking about the `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"` in the `local.settings.json`, then no. Where does one do that? Thanks!

Comment: could you try copy pasting the connection string as mentioned here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/357

Comment: Like a connection string from my Azure storage account?

Comment: Yes ! Correct! Try to replace

Comment: Ah, so sub that in for the `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"`, essentially. Will try to see if that runs locally. So I tried it, but no change to the Docker container when I run it. But I did see that `local.settings.json` is ignored in `.dockerignore`